# <identifier> expected error when using a Search object

Tags: java

what is the solution of this error

```
public static void main(String[]args){

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  String KeySearch = in.nextLine();
  Search obj = new Search(KeySearch."list.txt");
  obj.ReadFile();
  obj.ShowPrice();
}

C:\Users\jody\Desktop\Search.java:67: error: <identifier> expected
      Search obj = new Search(KeySearch."list.txt");
                                        ^
C:\Users\jody\Desktop\Search.java:67: error: ';' expected
      Search obj = new Search(KeySearch."list.txt");
```

Comment: KeySearch."list.txt" isn't a thing, what are you tring to do

Comment: I have a file name list and I read it

Answer (score 3):

I *suspect* you meant to use a comma instead of a period. A comma would separate two arguments, whereas what you have right now is not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

You might have meant to concatenate the KeySearch string with "line.txt", in which case you need to use `+` rather than a period. This can happen if you have your PHP hat on :)

```
Search obj = new Search(KeySearch + "list.txt");
```